# How to put a button on the default keyboard? I want a button that when is pressed, it chance to another activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a EditText in my activity. I want that when the user finish the text, he can move to the next activity without press back button to hide the keyboard. I was wondering if there a way to put a button on softkeyboard to move to next activity.

(Sorry for bad english, its not my native language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add buttons to an existing keyboard. However, you can suggest a label and id for the custom IME action. See [`TextView.setImeActionLabel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeActionLabel%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29):

> Change the custom IME action associated with the text view, which will be reported to an IME with actionLabel and actionId when it has focus.

You'll then have to call [`TextView.setOnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29) to provide a custom listener to listen for that IME event where you can then move to your next activity.

Comment: I dont understood. I did it, and its only work on the virtual device. And this button only hide the keyboard. How do I implement the button to when pressed, it change to next activity?

Comment: You'll also have to listen for the custom IME action and handle it. I'll update the answer with a little more info.